# Wait for another thread to do something

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I have two threads, `A` and `B`. I want the following:

- I want to let `A` wait until `B` starts executing `f()`. Once `B` starts executing `f()`, A as well can continue its work.
- If `B` is already executing `f()` when `A` informs `B` for its state, `A` can continue its work as well.
- If however `B` finished executing `f()`, `A` has to wait until `B` starts executing `f()` again in the future.

In functions:

```
// executed by A only
public void waitForB() throws InterruptedException {
    // keep waiting until B starts f()
}

// executed within aroundF() only
public void f() {
}

// executed by B only
public void aroundF() {
    // 1. mark that we are executing f() and inform A
    f()
    // 2. unmark 
}
```

I have been trying with `Semaphore`, `Phaser` and `CyclicBarrier`, but I have troubles to understand which to use here.

I managed to implement this with locking manually (see below), but I would like to understand which of the `java.util.concurrent` classes to use here.

```
private final    Object  lock      = new Object();
private          boolean executing = false;

public void waitForB() throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized(lock) {
        while(!executing) {
            lock.wait();
        }
    }
}

public void f() {
}

public void aroundF() {
    try {
        synchronized(lock) {
            executing = true;
            lock.notify();
        }
        f();
    } finally {
        executing = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same semantics (and more) using `java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock` and an associated `java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition`, for instance:

```
public class MyClass {
  private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
  private final Condition condition = lock.newCondition();
  private boolean executing = false;

  public void waitForB() throws InterruptedException {
    lock.lock();
    try {
      while (!executing) {
        condition.await();
      }
    } finally {
      lock.unlock();
    }
  }

  public void f() {
  }

  public void aroundF() {
    try {
      lock.lock();
      try {
        executing = true;
        condition.signal();
      } finally {
        lock.unlock();
      }
      f();
    } finally {
      executing = false;
    }
  }
}
```